# Possible to use group policies configured with Office 2010 Administrative Template Files with office 2013?

Tags: group-policy, microsoft-office

I was simply wondering if group policy settings configured using the Office 2010 Group Policy Administrative Template files (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=18968
) apply to later versions of Office, such as Office 2013, or if I need to download new brand new template files (i.e. for Office 2013) and reconfigure the old settings from 2010 all over again with the new templates. If this is a case, is there any way to copy the settings over so I don't have to configure them manually again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Short Answer - no, you can't use the GPO templates for one version to control a different version.  Some settings may work, but it would be bad practice.

The Microsoft Office group policy templates contain both specific-version and version-neutral settings.  Some settings are implemented by version specific registry paths, eg

```
HKCU\software\policies\microsoft\Office\14.0\publisher\file mru\max display
```

While others are in 'generic' registry paths, eg

```
HKCU\software\policies\microsoft\office\common\workflow\home
```

The reference sheet that Microsoft provides handily separates the settings into version-specific and non-versioned settings, you can obtain that reference here: http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/8/A/18AAAD2F-4CFB-4AE3-A6BA-FEEE615931CF/GroupPolicySettingsReference_Office2010.xlsx

I'm afraid I don't know of any way to programmatically duplicate the 2010 GPO settings into the 2013 GPO.  This will be further complicated as the available settings are not identical across the versions.

Comment: @wrieedx His answer is factual - as pointed out, many of the policies are version specific as seen in the registry path. Some may work, but that's pure coincidence - it's a manual job to copy over but it doesn't take that long really. Best to get the new ones for any updated settings and descriptions - anyway.